# Updating .net 2 winforms to .net 4 now it's affected by UAC

Tags: .net, winforms, uac

My winforms .net 2 program runs fine in windows 7 with UAC turned on. The program reads/writes `c:/program files` folder.
After updating the program to target .net 4, the same program is affected by UAC and it cannot read/write `c:/program files` anymore. I get `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I **know** it's a bad practice to read/write `c:/program files` but I'm wondering what's causing this behavior?

Comment: .net 4.0 has considerable changes to Code Access Security. That may be the area to look for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible, there were no changes in Winforms or the .NET Framework in general that made writing to c:\program files suddenly forbidden.  Or for that matter possible.

The only possible explanation I can think of is that you previously used Visual Studio 2005.  The original RTM version without the Vista service pack.  Which shipped *before* Vista so did not yet add the manifest to the EXE that's required to let Windows know that your program is UAC compatible.  You can see what that manifest looks like with Project + Add New Item, General, Application Manifest File.  The essential entry is:

```
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

To be able to write to c:\program files, you must change the `level` attribute to "requireAdministrator".

Without that manifest entry, Windows will treat your program as a legacy program that doesn't know about UAC yet.  So it *looks* like you can write to c:\program files.  But not really, Windows redirects the file access to isolated storage.

Changing the manifest will work but is probably not going to be received terribly well if your user runs your program frequently.  Making your code compatible with UAC is the better solution, write files to AppData instead.

Comment: The old program was built using VS2005! However it's a C++/CLI program I cannot find a way to add the manifest file. Is it already embedded somehow in the program?

Comment: Well, score one for psychic debugging.  Linker + Manifest File options, the VS version matters.  Before you go there, do consider fixing the real problem.